# Path of an ellipse

Tags: polar-coordinates

A path is described by the position vector $\mathbf{r}$:
$$\mathbf{r}=a\cos(\omega t)\mathbf{\hat{i}}+b\sin{\omega t}\mathbf{\hat{j}}$$
I am asked to show that the path is the ellipse in the form of:
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

Is this not converting from polar to cartesian using $x=\mathbf{r}\cos(\omega t)$ and $y=\mathbf{r}\sin(\omega t)$? When I tried this I got as far as $x^2+y^2-ax-by=0$ and I am not sure what to do next, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider above $\bf{r}$ as $$\mathbf{r}=x(t)\mathbf{\hat{i}}+y(t)\mathbf{\hat{j}}$$ and then satisfy $x(t),~y(t)$ in the given Cartesian equation.

Comment: Still not seeing it, all I can think about doing from your hint is satisying $x(t)=\frac{x^2}{a^2}$ and $y(t)=\frac{y^2}{b^2}$ which you can't even do. Anything else and I end up where I got before

Comment: @Johnmgee: Babak S. is saying to you to put $x=a\cos{\omega t}$ and $y=b\sin{\omega t}\;$. So ...

Comment: + 1 $\ddot\smile$